# Migrations Plugin for CakePHP

Tags: database-migration, cakephp-2.3

I have few questions about [this plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations).

1- what does it do?

Is it for exchanging databases between teams or changing their schema or creating tables based on models or something else?

2- if it is not meant to create tables based on models where can I find a script that does this?

3-can it work under windows?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Migrations plugin allows versioning of your db changes.  Much like is available in other PHP frameworks and Rails.

You essentially start  with your original schema and create the initial migration.  Each time you make a change you generate a 'diff' that gets stored in the filesystem.

When you run a migration, the database is updated with the changes you made.  Think deployment to a staging or production server where you want the structure to be the same as your code is moved from environment to environment.

We are starting to look at this plugin so we can automate our deployments, as the DB changes are done manually right now.